# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: PKIX path building failed | Unable to make ssl connection to postgre server

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc

I'm trying to make jdbc connection to a SSL enable postgre server using the server's public key that I imported to cacerts.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

 public class TestPostgreSql {

/**
 * Connect to the PostgreSQL database
 *
 * @return a Connection object
 * @throws SQLException 
 * @throws KeyStoreException 
 */
public Connection connect() throws SQLException, KeyStoreException {
    Connection conn = null;
    
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "postgres");
    props.setProperty("password", "postgres");
    props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
    props.put("sslmode", "require");
    props.setProperty("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.DefaultJavaSSLFactory");
  props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/Users/siena/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts");
       props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/", props);
       
      System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, KeyStoreException {
    
    TestPostgresql db = new TestPostgresql();
    db.connect();

}
```

}

But getting the below exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at com.spdr.datasecurity.rdbms.enumeration.launchenum.TestPostgresql.connect(TestPostgresql.java:95)
    at com.spdr.datasecurity.rdbms.enumeration.launchenum.TestPostgresql.main(TestPostgresql.java:112)
```

Am I missing anything?

I tried with,

```
props.put("sslmode", "require");
props.setProperty("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory");
```

But this only works when the server is not set to allow only SSL connections.

Comment: Please incude the necessary `import`s so we don't need to guess.